# Screen-witdh depended menu toggle and auto open in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a side-panel menu for a school project website. After browsing around a bit, I found [This codepen](http://codepen.io/joshbader/pen/iduef).

The Javascript code that originally comes with the codepen is as follows:

```
$('.menu a, .nav a').on('click', function () {  
   $('.wrapper').toggleClass('active');  
});
```

Now, what i'm trying to do, is to make the menu on this page, which uses JQuery for toggling, Automatically open if the browser window width goes below 720 pixels.

I've found another part of JQuery-Javascript, that tought me how to use the browser width. After merging that with the existing code above, I ended on this:

```
function checkWindowSize() {  
    if ( $(window).width() < 720 )  {
        var smallscreen = true;
    }  
    else {  
        var smallscreen = false;  
        $('.wrapper').toggleClass('active');  
    }  
}  

if (smallscreen = true)  {
    $('.menu a, .nav a').on('click', function () {  
        $('.wrapper').toggleClass('active');  
    });  
}
```

Again, what i need it to do is this:

- On page load or resize, check the browser window's width
- If it's under 720px, enable the toggle code for the menu so it auto-hides
- If it's over 720px, disable the toggle for the menu, un-hide the menu, and keep it open.
- Optitionally, hide the menu button (class .menu) when the browser is over 720px wide and make it re-appear when the window size comes under 720px

As this is my 1st Stackoverflow question and my first actually practical use of Javascript, please bear with me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will achieve this easiest by using `CSS` @media anotation:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    // your needed style here
}
```

If you have different sizes, devices or needs check [CSS3@media rule](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

**IMPORTANT**: to me I need to define ALL sizes to have correct behaviour when we have transitions in screen size, so to avoid weird things you must define something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
    /* STYLES HERE */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    /* STYLES HERE */
}
```

Comment: After a little playing around, I got it to work exactly as I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: great to hear this... feel free to accept as correct answer ;)